# Get previous 10 seconds

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to list the datetime with previous 10 seconds.

I tried with this

```
 SELECT    (SYSDATE -LEVEL + 1) each_day
    FROM DUAL
 CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10
```

But I get previous 10 days.

Is it possible to get previous 10 seconds?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible to get previous 10 seconds?

You almost got it:

```
 SELECT    (SYSDATE  + (1-LEVEL)/24/3600 ) each_sec
 --                     ^^^^^^^
 --                   including the 'current' sysdate
 --                   (as LEVEL start at 1)
    FROM DUAL
 CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10
```

---

If you are open to the use of the [`INTERVAL`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF00221) data type, you might prefer using [`NUMTODSINTERVAL`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions108.htm#SQLRF00682) as it is somehow more self-documenting:

```
 SELECT    SYSDATE  + NUMTODSINTERVAL(1-LEVEL, 'SECOND') each_sec
    FROM DUAL
 CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10
```

Comment: `NUMTODSINTERVAL` is a useful addition. +1

Answer (score 2):

Substracting from `SYSDATE` is in days, so `- 1` is minus one day. To convert that into seconds, use:

```
select (sysdate - (level / 24 /*hours*/ / 3600 /*seconds*/)) each_second
from   dual
connect
by     level <= 10
```

Comment: Thank you. but this gives 10 seconds earlier for previous dates also. I need current date in all 10 records and one second less for each record. Like 22/12/2014 09:34:45...  22/12/2014 09:34:44...       22/12/2014 09:34:43

Comment: @Shanna I missed `level` in the query, my bad.

Comment: @Shanna: Please make a decision. Choose either of these answers... I hate that flashing sign in my screen.